# Recording audio and video after having played video with audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, avcapturesession

I'm building an app in which I can record video with audio input.

It works well: I use `AVCaptureSession` with two `AVCaptureDeviceInput`, one for video, one for audio.
I then record the movie with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.
Until now, no problem, my video gets recorded, and audio is present.

But I have a problem if I try to record this video with audio input after a video (with audio) has been played (with `AVPlayer`). Indeed, the video gets recorded, but there is no audio!

Three things:

I have tried to put `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];` before recording, it doesn't change anything.

Any `AVPlayer` instance is paused before trying to record anything.

The `AVPlayer` instance, even if paused, is still present when I try to record (is it a problem?)

I would like to say that I have this problem on my iPhone 4, but the same app, compiled on my iPad Air, works like a charm (there is audio in my recording even after having played a video...). How is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

Before taking video just

```
  [self.moviePlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
```